# Type Error, Angular 5: Cannot read property 'length'

Tags: angular, html, typescript

Still I got below error:
Type Error Cannot read property 'length', is connected to html line 9:

Test

```
</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell fxFlex="40%" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let element"
  line 9:    [ngStyle]="checkIfTrue(element.name) && {'background-color':'lightgreen'}">
          <mat-checkbox [ngStyle]="checkIfTrue(element.name) && {'background-color':'white'}" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null" [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
          </mat-checkbox>
          </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
```

And checkIfTrue from component:

```
   checkIfTrue(name?: string) {
    if (name) {
        if (!this.isLoadingArray[this.groupName]) {
            for (const team of this.teams) {
                if (name === team.teamPromotion1 || name === team.teamPromotion2) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

I think, all the values were initialized.

Comment: when you do console.log(name) in checkIfTrue(){} function, what are you seeing

Comment: Try `if (name)` instead of `if (name.length > 0)`.

Comment: @yer Properly results, without any null or undefined. Properly results + that same errors.

Comment: @CannorsFans after change to `if (name)` I have that same errors.

Comment: ```element.name``` is undefined in template. change it to ```element?name```

Comment: @ConnorsFan suggested trick should work and your error should not be same. OR you can try `name?.length` I am not sure that works in the `.ts` or not

Comment: You have not assigned any value to `<mat-cell fxFlex="40%" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let element"` **element**

Comment: @fateme fazli, after changed to element?name in [ngStyle] - still I have that same errors.

Comment: @Rohit.007 What do You mean? element value should has connection to dataSource (mat-table).

Comment: `element` is assigned just above and your code is retrieving the properties from blank element OR you can just write a `console.log(name)` just above the `if (name.length > 0) {` statement then you will get what value is passed into it.

Comment: Try binding your style this way: `[ngStyle]="checkIfTrue(element.name) ? {'background-color':'lightgreen'} : {}"`. And keep the condition in the method as `if (name) {...}`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan After those changing, the situation is thate same - errors. Additionally, if I added console.log after if(name), this log it's never written out, so if(name) always is true.

Comment: Make sure sure that you return `false` when the condition is false in your method (e.g. `if (name) {...} else { return false; }`).

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yes, I did it (updated source code in my question). Still that same wrong situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because element.name is not defined in html causes error and it's not work even if you change it to element?.name, you can do something like this:

```
<mat-cell *ngIf="element.name" fxFlex="40%" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let element"
[ngStyle]="checkIfTrue(element.name) && {'background-color':'lightgreen'}">
```

Comment: 'Can't have multiple template bindings one one element'. Also I can't wrap mat-cell  in div etc.

Comment: The error comes from checkIfTrue(), namely because element.name is undefined which doesn't have a length property

Comment: @baao but in `checkIfTrue(name?: string)` name is optional. Also I checked if name is exists `if ( name.length) `.

Comment: Yes. If you don't pass something you are checking for `undefined.length`.  undefined doesn't have a length property. Check `if (name && name.length)` @profiler

Comment: @baao i know but even if i change it to element.?name it causes error because it's methods parameter.

Comment: The html is not connected to this error @fatemefazli

Comment: @baao After change to `if (name && name.length)` unfortunately that same error on that same line. Strange situation.

Comment: yes as @baao said if you check ```if (name && name.length)``` in your function it prevent error.

Comment: @profiler may you check ```[ngStyle]="{'background-color' : checkIfTrue(element.name) ? null:'lightgreen'}"``` ?

Comment: @fatemefazli Checked it, and also still got the errors.

Comment: @profiler i think you are doing something wrong, check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e4l9nd).

Comment: @fatemefazli added also `if (this.teams)` before for loop, and it is working! Thank You for help!